# Resize Rectangle HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have some functions to draw rectangles on a canvas element. When the element is drawn, I want to be able to resize it by dragging its corners.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  rect = {},
  drag = false;

function init() {
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
  rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  drag = true;
}

function mouseUp() {
  drag = false;
}

function mouseMove(e) {
  if (drag) {
    rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
    rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    draw();
  }
}

function draw() {
  ctx.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
}

init();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: I edited my answer to be more complete

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Make sure to use some kind of threshold value to check for dragging on corners,  use a `closeEnough` variable to hold this threshold then check corners by seeing if the absolute value of the difference between corner point and mouse point is less than the threshold. Apart from that, it is just a lot of cases to go through. [Here is a jsFiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/Cpvxf/128/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    rect = {},
    drag = false,
    mouseX, 
    mouseY,
    closeEnough = 10,
    dragTL=dragBL=dragTR=dragBR=false;

function init() {
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
  mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

  // if there isn't a rect yet
  if(rect.w === undefined){
    rect.startX = mouseY;
    rect.startY = mouseX;
    dragBR = true;
  }

  // if there is, check which corner
  //   (if any) was clicked
  //
  // 4 cases:
  // 1. top left
  else if( checkCloseEnough(mouseX, rect.startX) && checkCloseEnough(mouseY, rect.startY) ){
    dragTL = true;
  }
  // 2. top right
  else if( checkCloseEnough(mouseX, rect.startX+rect.w) && checkCloseEnough(mouseY, rect.startY) ){
    dragTR = true;

  }
  // 3. bottom left
  else if( checkCloseEnough(mouseX, rect.startX) && checkCloseEnough(mouseY, rect.startY+rect.h) ){
    dragBL = true;

  }
  // 4. bottom right
  else if( checkCloseEnough(mouseX, rect.startX+rect.w) && checkCloseEnough(mouseY, rect.startY+rect.h) ){
    dragBR = true;

  }
  // (5.) none of them
  else {
    // handle not resizing
  }

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  draw();

}

function checkCloseEnough(p1, p2){
  return Math.abs(p1-p2)<closeEnough;
}
function mouseUp() {
  dragTL = dragTR = dragBL = dragBR = false;
}

function mouseMove(e) {
  mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  if(dragTL){
    rect.w += rect.startX-mouseX;
    rect.h += rect.startY-mouseY;
    rect.startX = mouseX;
    rect.startY = mouseY;
  } else if(dragTR) {
    rect.w = Math.abs(rect.startX-mouseX);
    rect.h += rect.startY-mouseY;
    rect.startY = mouseY;
  } else if(dragBL) {
    rect.w += rect.startX-mouseX;
    rect.h = Math.abs(rect.startY-mouseY);
    rect.startX = mouseX;  
  } else if(dragBR) {
    rect.w = Math.abs(rect.startX-mouseX);
    rect.h = Math.abs(rect.startY-mouseY);
  }
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    draw();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
}

init();
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? It is working fine for me. I updated the fiddle to make it more obvious what is going on.

Comment: Nicely done, I like the handles so the user knows how to use it.

Answer (score 15):

Do a handle system: when the mouse move, get the distance to each corner to get the first one that is near the cursor then save it and resize your rectangle according to it.

Here is a JSfiddle illustrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/BaliBalo/9HXMG/

```
function getHandle(mouse) {
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y)) <= handlesSize) return 'topleft';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y)) <= handlesSize) return 'topright';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize) return 'bottomleft';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize) return 'bottomright';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w / 2, rect.y)) <= handlesSize) return 'top';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y + rect.h / 2)) <= handlesSize) return 'left';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w / 2, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize) return 'bottom';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y + rect.h / 2)) <= handlesSize) return 'right';
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is oldish, but for people like me who stumbled on this issue, I put together various ideas (thanks, @Paul Kaplan) and packed an up-and-running [solution](https://catloader-api.variancedigital.com/bo/selectthumbnail) **that works even on a responsive canvas**.

The code is visible in the linked HTML page source and explained in [this](https://medium.com/variance-digital/interactive-rectangular-selection-on-a-responsive-image-761ebe24280c?source=friends_link&sk=f66843c98fa5d937b3d47a848ede5674) article ("Interactive selection box on a responsive image").

I'm sure it may help.