# How to create a resizable rectangle in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

What I mean is that the user presses a mouse button at point xy on an HTML canvas and while the mouse button is pressed the rectangle can be resized according to the movement of the cursor with point xy fixed. Like how highlighting works.

This is what I've got so far but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
 canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){

var rectx = e.clientX;
var recty = e.clientY;

canvas.onmousemove = function(e){     



    var df = e.clientX;
    var fg = e.clientY;
};


context.rect(rectx, recty, df-rectx, fg-recty);
context.stroke();




}, false);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize Rectangle HTML5 Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470956/resize-rectangle-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming there are no transforms (`scale`, `translate`) on your canvas context.*

Basic steps for having a resizable rectangle are as follows:

1. Create a `mousedown` listener that sets a flag indicating the use is holding down the mouse button, as well as sets the "anchor," or initial coordinates.
2. Create a `mouseup` listener that unsets the flag.
3. Create a `mousemove` listener that, if the flag indicates the mouse is down, redraws the canvas with the rectangle's size changed according to mouse coordinates.

An important note is that client coordinates in the `event` object are relative to the page, **not to your canvas element**. You will frequently need to convert `clientX` and `clientY` into canvas coordinates:

```
var getCanvasCoords = function (clientX, clientY) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    return {
        x: clientX - rect.left,
        y: clientY - rect.top
    };
};
```

The first two steps look something like this:

```
var anchorX;
var anchorY;
var mouseDown = false;    

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    var coords = getCanvasCoords(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    anchorX = coords.x;
    anchorY = coords.y;

    mouseDown = true;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
    mouseDown = false;
});
```

And the `mousemove` handler:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    var coords = getCanvasCoords(event.clientX, event.clientY);

    var width = coords.x - anchorX;
    var height = coords.y - anchorY;

    // clear canvas for redrawing
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.fillRect(anchorX, anchorY, width, height);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Don't Render from mouse events!

The given answer is correct but it is not the best way to do this.

The are two reasons. First the mousemove event can fire up to 600+ times a second but the display only refreshes 60 times a second. Rendering from the input event is many time just a waste of CPU time as the results will be overwritten by the next mouse event before it is ever had a chance to be displayed.

The second reason is that dedicating an event listener to a single task makes it hard to add more functionality. You end up adding more and more code to the mousemove event to handle all the types of input, most of which can be ignored because of the high update speed of the mouse.

#### Mouse listeners

Mouse event listeners do the minimum possible. They just record the mouse state and no more. Also all mouse events return the mouse position. You should not ignore the mouse position for events like mouse down and up

The following function creates a mouse object for a element. The mouse object has the x,y position relative to the to left of the element, and the current button states for 3 buttons it is left to right button1, button2, button3.

Also when the mouse leaves the element and then releases the mouse button the mouse for the element will not see the mouseup event and not know the mouse button is up. To prevent the mouse buttons from getting stuck you turn off the buttons when the mouse leaves the element.

The best mouse listener is to the whole page as it can track mouse events that happen even when the mouse is outside the window/tab (if the window/tab has focus), but that is a little to complex for this answer.

Function to create a mouse for an element

```
function createMouse(element){
    var mouse = {
       x : 0,
       y : 0,
       button1 : false,
       button2 : false,
       button3 : false,
       over : false,
    };
    function mouseEvent(event){
        var bounds = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouse.x = event.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
        mouse.y = event.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
        if(event.type === "mousedown"){
            mouse["button"+event.which] = true;
        } else if(event.type === "mouseup"){
            mouse["button"+event.which] = false;
        } else if(event.type === "mouseover"){
            mouse.over = true;
        } else if(event.type === "mouseout"){
            mouse.over = false;
            mouse.button1 = false;  // turn of buttons to prevent them locking
            mouse.button2 = false;
            mouse.button3 = false;
        }
        event.preventDefault(); // stops default mouse behaviour.
    }
    var events = "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover".split(',');
    events.forEach(eventType => element.addEventListener(eventType,mouseEvent));
    mouse.remove = function(){
        events.forEach(eventType => element.removeEventListener(eventType, mouseEvent));
    }
    return mouse;
}
```

#### Using the mouse

It is now just a matter of creating a mouse for the element

```
var canMouse = createMouse(canvas);
```

And then in your main render loop do the dragging.

```
var drag = { 
    x : 0,
    y : 0,
    x1 : 0,
    y1 : 0,
    dragging : false,
    top : 0,
    left : 0,
    width : 0,
    height : 0,
}

function mainLoop(){
     if(canMouse.button1){  // is button down
         if(!drag.dragging){ // is dragging
             drag.x = canMouse.x;
             drag.y = canMouse.y;
             drag.dragging = true;
         }
         drag.x1  = canMouse.x;
         drag.y1  = canMouse.y;
         drag.top = Math.min(drag.y, drag.y1);
         drag.left = Math.min(drag.x, drag.x1);
         drag.width = Math.abs(drag.x - drag.x1);
         drag.height = Math.abs(drag.y - drag.y1);
     }else{
         if(drag.dragging){
             drag.dragging = false;
         }
     }
 }
```

#### Putting it all together

```js
    function createMouse(element){
        var mouse = {
           x : 0,
           y : 0,
           button1 : false,
           button2 : false,
           button3 : false,
           over : false,
        };
        function mouseEvent(event){
            var bounds = element.getBoundingClientRect();
          
            // NOTE getting the border should not be done like this as
            // it will not work in all cases. 
            var border = Number(element.style.border.split("px")[0])
            
            mouse.x = event.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX - border;
            mouse.y = event.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY - border;
            if(event.type === "mousedown"){
                mouse["button"+event.which] = true;
            } else if(event.type === "mouseup"){
                mouse["button"+event.which] = false;
            } else if(event.type === "mouseover"){
                mouse.over = true;
            } else if(event.type === "mouseout"){
                mouse.over = false;
                mouse.button1 = false;  // turn of buttons to prevent them locking
                mouse.button2 = false;
                mouse.button3 = false;
            }
            event.preventDefault(); // stops default mouse behaviour.
        }
        var events = "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover".split(',');
        events.forEach(eventType => element.addEventListener(eventType,mouseEvent));
        mouse.remove = function(){
            events.forEach(eventType => element.removeEventListener(eventType, mouseEvent));
        }
        return mouse;
    }
    var drag = {
        x : 0,
        y : 0,
        x1 : 0,
        y1 : 0,
        dragging : false,
        top : 0,
        left : 0,
        width : 0,
        height : 0,
    }
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    var mouse = createMouse(canvas);
    function update(){
         ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
         if(mouse.button1){  // is button down
             if(!drag.dragging){ // is dragging
                 drag.x = mouse.x;
                 drag.y = mouse.y;
                 drag.dragging = true;
             }
             drag.x1  = mouse.x;
             drag.y1  = mouse.y;
             drag.top = Math.min(drag.y, drag.y1);
             drag.left = Math.min(drag.x, drag.x1);
             drag.width = Math.abs(drag.x - drag.x1);
             drag.height = Math.abs(drag.y - drag.y1);
         }else{
             if(drag.dragging){
                 drag.dragging = false;
             }
         }
      
         if(drag.dragging){
            ctx.strokeRect(drag.left, drag.top, drag.width, drag.height);
         }
         requestAnimationFrame(update);
     }
     requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
canvas {
  border : 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
Click drag to draw rectangle.<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width= "512" height = "256"></canvas>
```